# esp8266 client connect failed with cdn proxy

Tags: proxy, cdn, esp8266, esp8266wifi

I have set an Arduino code (on an esp8266). The code is only doing the following :

- Set wifi
- Connect to a webserver
- Retrieve the html from this webserver and store it
- instantiate a server:port
- handle GET "/" request on local IP address and send back the html from the previous webserver.

Code is working fine (on 99%). I just need some support on the remaining 1%. :-)

1. When the webserver is having a "normal" IP address+domain name, the esp8266 can resolve it without any issue.
2. When the webserver is having only a "normal" IP address on the LAN, the esp8266 can get html from it without any issue.
3. But when this webserver is behind a CDN/Proxy activated (FYI this is Cloudflare), then the IP resolution is the IP from the CDN (seems OK) ; but the esp get an empty html or maybe a "0"... I'm not able to debug deeply on esp.

Is there anything I missed in my setting ?
Any idea what should I try.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to BearSSL Arduino library to and some final point after getting SSL handshake Error 40.
So in the end, I managed to use BearSSL and that solve the issue.